# angular-ui-routing doesn't change the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I have a problem with ionic and ui-routing, when I go in a child state the url is updated but the view remains the same.

this is my routing.js

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {

    $ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);

    $stateProvider

        .state('app', {
            url: "/",
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: "menu.html",
            controller: "menuCtrl"
        })

        .state('app.home', {
            url: "home",
            cache: false,
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: "home.html",
                    controller: "homeCtrl"
                }
            }
        })

        .state('app.search', {
            url: "search",
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: "search.html",
                    controller: "searchCtrl"
                }
            }
        })

        .state('app.search.product', {
            url: "/product/:id",
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: "productPage.html",
                    controller: "singleProductCtrl"
                }
            }
        })

        .state('app.search.product.market', {
            url: "/product/:id",
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: "market.html",,
                    controller: "marketCtrl'
                }
            }
        });
    // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
});
```

in this example when I try to go in app.search.product the view doesn't change, even if I go there directly inserting the right url in the browser. I've also tryed with ui-sref-opts="{reload: true} option but nothing change.

Here's a plunker that shows the problem (after search the view doesn't change) https://plnkr.co/edit/JrNFkV50klZItOQS18Iu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have experience with Ionic, but based on the ui-router config angular expects a nested view, but your page has only single view. Meaning, the second level (product) has no view to load into. Since Ionic I suppose doesn't allow nested ionic views (would be funny if it did) you can use normal ui-view as nested one.

```
<ion-view view-title="Search">
<ion-content>
    <h1>Search</h1>
    <a ui-sref=".product({id: 1})">Go to product</a>
    <ui-view name="secondLevel"></ui-view>
</ion-content>
```

Check your code with modifications here: https://plnkr.co/edit/LdgmoAEo1pS9spi1Su1z.

Not sure if this is what you were looking for. Based on your plunkr it looks like you've defined nested view accidentally. In which case solution would be to remove **.search** from ***.product** state names: https://plnkr.co/edit/PGICsBhzyCOTSe9af4yu

```
        .state('app.product', {
            url: "/product/:id",
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: "productPage.html"
                }
            }
        })

        .state('app.market', {
            url: "/product/:id",
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: "market.html"
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: thanks, I've used this...also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36426578/6160786) is working

Answer (score 2):

Use this configuration:

```
   $stateProvider

        .state('app', {
            url: "/",
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: "menu.html",
        })

        .state('app.home', {
            url: "home",
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: "home.html"
                }
            }
        })

        .state('app.search', {
            url: "search",
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: "search.html"
                }
            }
        })

        .state('app.product', {
            url: "/product/:id",
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: "productPage.html"
                }
            }
        })

        .state('app.market', {
            url: "/product/:id",
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: "market.html"
                }
            }
        });
```

When you declare 'app.search.product' by example, this means that in the template of the search state (search.html) should be have a view for load the children state, and this it's not the case, your views has been moving in the same "level"

Answer (score 0):

try to put in ui-sref name of the product state in Go To product link tag.
that is ui-sref="app.product"